# Beginner Java Boolean Logic Comparing inputted values

Tags: java, boolean

I'm a beginner with Java, and I'm trying to figure out an exercise.  I'm supposed to use basic boolean logic.  The concept is:

Enter 1st monster's name : Tom
Enter 1st monster's size : 2
Enter 2nd monster's name : Bob
Enter 2nd monster's size : 4

Monster 1 – Tom 2
Monster 2 – Bob 4

Monster one is smaller than Monster two.
Monster one does not have the same name as Monster two.

Enter 1st monster's name : Sally
Enter 1st monster's size : 7
Enter 2nd monster's name : Fred
Enter 2nd monster's size : 2

Monster 1 – Sally 7
Monster 2 – Fred 2

Monster one is bigger than Monster two.
Monster one does not have the same name as Monster two.

I have the first part ("Monster 1 Sally 7, Monster 2 Fred 2"), but I am not sure how to make the boolean comparisons work.  i'm stuck. :-(

Using jcreator, I have a "Monster.java" tab that reads:

```
import static java.lang.System.*; 

public class Monster
{
    private String name;
    private int howBig; 

    public Monster()
    {


    }

    public Monster(String n, int size)
    {
        name = n;
        howBig = size;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHowBig()
    {
        return howBig;
    }

    public boolean isBigger(Monster other)
    {
         if(getHowBig() > other.getHowBig()) {
            return false;
         }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isSmaller(Monster other)
    {
        //call isBigger() use !
        if(getHowBig() < other.getHowBig()) {
            return false;
         }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean namesTheSame(Monster other)
    {
        if(name != other.name)  {
            return false;
         }
        return true;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

and a "MonsterRunner.java" tab that reads:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*; 

public class MonsterRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask for name and size
        out.print("Enter 1st monster's name :: ");
        String a = kb.next();
        out.print("Enter 1st monster's size :: ");
        int b = kb.nextInt();

        //ask for name and size
        out.print("Enter 2nd monster's name :: ");
        String c = kb.next();
        out.print("Enter 2nd monser's size :: ");
        int d = kb.nextInt();

        //instantiate monster one
        Monster test = new Monster(a,b);
        out.println("Monster 1 - " + test.getName() + " " + test.getHowBig() );

        //instantiate monster two
        Monster go = new Monster(c,d);
        out.println("Monster 2 - " + go.getName() + " " + go.getHowBig() );

        out.print("Monster 1 is ");

    }
}
```

Comment: [Nuts and Bolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific with how you are "not sure how to make the boolean comparisons work."? I would suggest reading the link from nullpointer since it gives you more insight into comparison statements in Java. I don't know how you want your isBigger and isSmaller methods to work but you might want to look at the size comparison you are doing. Currently isBigger returns true if other is bigger than the monster you are comparing it to (monster the function is being called from is smaller than "other") and vice versa with isSmaller, so I personally would reverse those two. You also don't need to getHowBig in isBigger and isSmaller for the first Monster object (still need it for other since this is a different object) since howBig is a part of the class.